# ctrl + [1 .. 6] resulting in soundbite/taunt

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Today I accidentally discovered shortcuts that resulted in a small soundbite.

ctrl + 1 : [Young Frankenstein - Dramatic Music](https://youtu.be/l2hCFMLvLDI?t=1s)
ctrl + 2: [Wilhelm scream](https://youtu.be/xn6hhrX34Pw)
ctrl + 3: [ain't nobody got time for that](https://youtu.be/zGxwbhkDjZM?t=25s)
ctrl + 4: [boom headshot](https://youtu.be/FZU88SkLyY0)
ctrl + 5: [developers developers developers developers](https://youtu.be/Vhh_GeBPOhs)
ctrl + 6: [just do it](https://youtu.be/ZXsQAXx_ao0?t=3s)

Other numbers don't seem to have any effect.
The shortcut works even if I don't have any programs open. I was a bit surprised I found this and was wondering if anyone can tell me where this comes from or how I could best find out?

Google just leads me to games that use the shortcuts or the taunts.

Comment: I would suggest talking to anyone else who may have had access to your computer... sounds like a prank application, of which there are dozens, maybe hundreds, out there. Whoever did it will likely not be able to keep a straight face.

Comment: I doubt it and would like to be able to find it. Any other stackexchange forum that is better suited for this question? I don't really see the reason of the downvote

Comment: Do you have [Nahimic](http://www.nahimic.com/) installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a feature of [Nahimic](http://www.nahimic.com/), a software audio "enhancer" that is apparently bundled with [MSI computers](https://www.msi.com/page/nahimic).

From [Nahimic's website](http://www.nahimic.com/specifications):

> **Audio LaunchPad**
>
> This tool allows to trigger audio samples of your choice with your keyboard or gamepad while recording or streaming
>   a gaming session.

Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qc5LTvXjQyM

[To turn it off](https://nahimic.helprace.com/i42-how-can-i-switch-on-off-the-audio-launchpad):

> **How can I switch ON / OFF the Audio Launchpad?**
>
> You can switch ON / OFF the Audio Launchpad on the page 2 of the HD Audio Recorder 2's tab and clicking on button beside Audio Launchpad ON / OFF. You can also use the hotkey CTRL + SHIFT + L to ON / OFF the Launchpad.
>   If you are using this hotkey while in a game, a pop up will appear to notify you whether the Launchpad is set to ON or OFF.

Answer (score 0):

I found when pressing ctrl-1 through ctrl-5 (when in any application or even just on the desktop) would for a second display a (loading) rotating circle mouse cursor.
Normally this isn't a problem, but on some applications (e.g. various strategy games, where ctrl-1 is a common thing to do), this actually makes it lose focus on the application window. And when running old applications in compatibility mode this even made some of them crash out.

The source of these ctrl-1 through ctrl-5 were apparently the MSI Dragon Control Center: When I exit it (right-click on the Dragon Center icon in your bottom right system tray, then Exit), this behaviour stops and everything works as normal.

I have no idea what ctrl-1 through ctrl-5 do for MSI Dragon Center, I could see no effects to them, no changed settings or anything.

---

I'm not sure if this is somehow related to Nahimic (which I also have on this MSI machine), but anyone running into the problems described in your question might also suffer from the one I describe (as most MSI machines have both Nahimic and the Dragon Center pre installed).